# Replicating previous month data if current month is null

Tags: sql

How do I write a SQL query where if values are null for current month it will populate with values from previous month, thanks for your help

Comment: You could use the LAG function in a case statement perhaps. What have you tried? Have an example query for us to start with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To be honest I am new to SQL and do not know how to start I just know basics of select and joins I will try to work on some sample code and post results.  Thanks for getting back to me so soon

Answer (score 0):

You should note which type of SQL you are using and provide some example data to help people help you...

In Oracle, you could use the **LAG** function within a **case** statement like so:

If the data looks like this:

```
MONTH    |    Value
___________________
JAN2016  |   100.00
FEB2016  |
MAR2016  |   342.60
APR2016  |   450.20
```

Code:

```
SELECT
    MONTH,
    CASE WHEN Value is null then LAG(Value OVER MONTH,1) else Value END as Value
FROM
    myTable;
```

The result would be:

```
    MONTH    |    Value 
________________________
    JAN2016  |   100.00
    FEB2016  |   100.00
    MAR2016  |   342.60
    APR2016  |   450.20
```

This solution will work as long as you don't have two or more consecutive months with a null value... if that is happening then your solution will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks that will be my start and will ask question better next go round thanks again everyone....